# php file_exists doesnt work when working with AWS PHP SDK

Tags: php, file, file-upload, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using AWS PHP SDK to get an object from S3 bucket.

when i look in the file system the files exist but the function file_exist return false.

If i run the script again it will find the file.

```
$result = $client->getObject(array(
            'Bucket' => "uploads/$id",
            'Key' => $file,
            'SaveAs' => "somepath/$id/$file"
        ));
echo json_encode(file_exists("somepath/$id/$file"));
```

this return FALSE but if i run the script again and manually inserting the url it will return TRUE.

can it be that while the script is still running i can't get the file? (maybe a timing issue?)

thx

Answer (score 1):

The method you are looking for is file_exists, not file_exist

```
echo json_encode(file_exists("somepath/$id/$file"));
```

Comment: And the existence of somepath/id/file is relative to where the script is executing? I.e. if my script is at /var/www/html/index.php - and i'm looking for somepath/1/filename then /var/www/html/somepath/1/filename is what you are verifying exists?

Comment: yes, i even echo to screen the file location, copied it and then ran the script again with that path and then the result was true

Comment: Just for giggles, do this for me: echo json_encode(file_exists("somepath/{$id}/{$file}"));

Comment: false... :( i also echo the "somepath/{$id}/{$file}" and then i ran the script again hardcoding the output and the result was true! going crazy...